# MYSQL Performance Tuning with group by clause

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a query like this.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM table1 e
WHERE e.column1=1
  AND e.id IN
    (SELECT MAX(ID)
     FROM table2 A
     WHERE A.column1=1
       AND A.date=CURDATE()
     GROUP BY A.column2);
```

When I run this query it is taking too much of time as I am having thousands of records. How can I tune the query to perform better.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: column2 in table2 is id of Table1

Comment: Read about the EXPLAIN statement here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html

Comment: @MahmoudGamal table1's id is related to table2 as OneToMany. Thats why I need max(id).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change in (. . .) To use join instead. Like

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM table1 AS e
Inner join   
(
  SELECT MAX(ID) 
  FROM table2 A
  WHERE A.column1 = 1 
    AND A.date = CURDATE() 
  GROUP BY A.column2
) t2 on e.id = t2.id
WHERE e.column1 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM table1 e
WHERE e.column1=1
  AND EXISTS 
    (SELECT *
     FROM table2 A
     WHERE A.column1=1
       AND A.date=CURDATE()
       AND A.ID = e.id);
```